# Laravel does update instead of delete

Tags: php, laravel

So I am adding an unsubscribe button to my notification email. So far there is no problem, until I try to execute it. I try to add an unsubscribe method in my subscribers controller in Laravel but it did not seem to delete the record in my table. When I try to delete, the record in my table is not deleted. Instead, it updates the column of my table.

This is my table column:

| id | name | email | confirmation_token | unsubscribe_token | created_at | deleted_at |

It updates the column deleted at with the time that I delete the record. In other words, the record that I want to delete still exists in my table, only the column deleted at is updated.

What could go wrong here? Codes are provided below. I am using Laravel 5.5 and PyroCMS 3.3. I think Pyro should not be the main problem here because these codes focus more on Laravel.

**On my route**:

```
'subscribers/u/{token}/id/{id}' => [
            'as'    => 'sands.module.communications::subscribers.unsubscribe',
            'uses'  => 'Sands\CommunicationsModule\Http\Controller\SubscribersController@unsubscribe'
```

**on my controller:**

```
public function unsubscribe(Request $request, MessageBag $messages, $token, $id)
    {

        $subscriber = SubscriberModel::whereStatus('active')->whereId($id)->whereUnsubscribeToken($token)->first();

        if(empty($token) or empty($subscriber))
        {
            $messages->error(trans('sands.module.communications::addon.subscribers.invalid-confirmation'));
            return redirect(url('/'));
        }

        $subscriber->delete();

        $messages->success(trans('sands.module.communications::addon.subscribers.unsubscribed'));
        return redirect(url('/'));
    }
```

**on my notification email:**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
    //tender name
    $tender = $this->title;

    //tender url
    $url = url($this->tender->site_link);

    // unsubscribe url
    $url_unsubscribe = route('sands.module.communications::subscribers.unsubscribe', 
    [
        'token' => $this->subscriber->unsubscribe_token, 
        'id' => $this->subscriber->id]);

      return (new MailMessage)
      ->markdown( 'mails.tender', [
          'url'         => $url,
          'url_unsubscribe' => $url_unsubscribe,
          'tender' => $tender] );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a "soft delete". Soft deleted items will be excluded by default from future queries, making them effectively deleted.

The [Laravel docs cover more about soft deletion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting). You can use `forceDelete` to actually delete the rows in your table.

The nice thing about soft deletion is that you don't end up getting rid of data you might want in the future. For example, if someone manages to "delete" all of your items, you can simply undo all the "deleted_at" modifications instead of having to recover from backup.

It also tracks when the items were deleted, which can be interesting analytics for you.

If you want to query for items including soft deleted ones in the future, you can use [withTrashed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) to retrieve all of them, regardless of deleted_at value.

Comment: You have clearly answered my question regarding Laravel. In this case, I really want my subscribers to be deleted from my table. I guess I would need to use forceDelete() to work.

Comment: Great! I've edited my response to include that information in case anyone else comes along.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of delete one is permanent delete which deletes the record from database and you will not be able to retrieve that again and second soft delete which only updates the deleted_at column in the table with the current time stamp .  Soft delete will automatically works in laravel if you used the trait use softdelete in your model but if  you want to delete that permanently just remove that trait from the model in laravel and it will delete that record permanently.

Comment: I vote you up because you give me the right answer as the comment above too :)
Your comment might be useful for anyone in the future too, so you have one vote for me.